# Regarding glMapBufferRange

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

```
    GLfloat vertices4[]={-0.9,0.6, -0.9,0.2, -0.6,0.2, -0.6,0.6,
                         -0.4,0.6, -0.4,0.2,  0.1,0.2,  0.1,0.6,
                          0.3,0.6,  0.3,0.2,  0.6,0.2,  0.6,0.6  };

     GLushort indices[]={0,1,2,3, 120, 4,5,6,7, 120, 8,9,10,11};
     GLenum *value=GL_STREAM_DRAW;  
     GLfloat temp_err;

     glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
     nResult =GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)"));

     glPrimitiveRestartIndex(120);
     nResult = GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glPrimitiveRestartIndex(120);"));

     glGenBuffers(1,&bufferid1);
     nResult = GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glGenBuffers(1,&bufferid1)"));

     glGenBuffers(1,bufferid);

     glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,bufferid);      
     glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices4),vertices4,*value);

     temp_err=(GLfloat*)glMapBufferRange(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER,0,8*sizeof(GLfloat),GL_MAP_READ_BIT);


     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferid1);
     nResult = GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferid1);")); 

     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,8*sizeof(GLfloat),temp_err,*value);


     *attr_vertex = glGetAttribLocation(shader_data.psId, "a_position"); 
     nResult = GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glGetAttribLocation(shader_data.psId, \"a_position\");"));

     glVertexAttribPointer(*attr_vertex, 2 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0, 0);
     nResult = GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glVertexAttribPointer(attr_vertex, 2 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,0, 0);"));

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(*attr_vertex);
     nResult = GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR,"glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_vertex);"));

     glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"offset_x"),x);                      
     glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader_data.psId,"offset_y"),y);                      
     glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 14,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indices);
```

I am expecting that it would render 1 quad as I am passing vertex data for the first quad in "bufferid1" but it renders all the 3 quads in vertices4. Please point me where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here i am expecting it would render 1 quad

How can you be expecting that? Your rendering call *specifically* says to render 14 vertices:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 14,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indices);
```

There's no reason for OpenGL to magically know that you only meant four this time.

Comment: But i am providing vertex data for 1 quad in buffer. Actually the same code renders 1 quad with ATI and nvidia card but it renders 3 quads on IMG driver.

Comment: @Roshan: It doesn't matter how big the buffer is; you said 14 vertices. Therefore, OpenGL is going to try to render what you asked it to. Since that means sampling beyond the size of the buffer, that means *undefined behavior*.